Is there a way to Mock the system date time in Aurora Postgres DB
I have a set of batch jobs which run on a specific day in the year end. The batch has multiple queries to get data from Aurora Postgres database. All the batches are multiple Java batches which has more than 300 queries which has clause to get System date time. I want to do a time dimensional testing, by mocking the date in my Aurora database.
Any query which is executed in that database and gets system date time it should give a preset value. Changing in all the queries and hard coding the date is a very tedious approach. Is there any other way to do this?
